# Row items into column based on row number present in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view

I have set of vehicle failed parts in a SQL Server table as per below:

| Vehicle_ID | Failed Part | RowNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | 1 |
| 1 | 0002 | 1 |
| 1 | 0003 | 1 |
| 1 | 0001 | 2 |
| 1 | 0006 | 2 |
| 1 | 0007 | 2 |
| 1 | 0001 | 3 |
| 1 | 0009 | 3 |
| 2 | 0001 | 1 |
| 2 | 0002 | 1 |
| 2 | 0003 | 2 |
| 2 | 0007 | 2 |
| 3 | 0006 | 1 |
| 3 | 0007 | 1 |
| 4 | 0011 | 1 |
| 4 | 0015 | 1 |
| 4 | 0016 | 1 |

`RowNumber` is the column we have to define the row. The results table like below. Maximum number of the `failed part` column count is 5.

| Vehicle_ID | Failed Part1 | Failed Part2 | Failed Part3 | Failed Part4 | Failed Part5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | 0002 | 0003 |  |  |
| 1 | 0001 | 0006 | 0007 |  |  |
| 1 | 0001 | 0009 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 0001 | 0002 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 0003 | 0007 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 0006 | 0007 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 0011 | 0015 | 0016 |  |  |

I tried below statement but could not arrive exact results.

```sql
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID,RowNumber)
                           ORDER BY [Failed Part]) rn
    FROM 
        VehicleTable
)
SELECT
    Vehicle_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart5
FROM 
    cte 
GROUP BY
    Vehicle_ID
```

Comment: You *literally* [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72301552) earlier...

Comment: As for why it failed; you don't have `RowNumber` as part of your  `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: HI Larnu, I forgot to add sql code which i tried to solve. Also i have deleted previous one

Comment: There is an [edit] feature for that, @Rock . Don't delete and repost questions; that'll just attract downvotes and wastes the time of the people that previously contributed to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added Rownumber in group by clause but results are not shown as per above required format

Comment: After fixing your typographical error at `Vehicle_ID,RowNumber)`, I can't replicate your problem: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6629da5106c842adb6e9192faa7a1fe9). If your attempt(s) aren't working, you'll need to supply a [mre] and explain *why* they aren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is really subtle. What you're doing is grouping on `Vehicle_ID`, problem is that there is more than one row for each `Vehicle_ID` in the output table. What you should do instead is fixing it by grouping also on the column number `rn` that you computed in the cte:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID, RowNumber
                                 ORDER BY [Failed Part]) rn
    FROM VehicleTable
)
SELECT
    Vehicle_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN [Failed Part] END) AS FailedPart5
FROM cte 
GROUP BY
    Vehicle_ID, rn
```

If you want your rows ordered as in the output, you just need to add `ORDER BY Vehicle_ID, rn` at the end.

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9775f9ac4d6c82e7767b3c106de98bf4).